# backtrack value which were chosen

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, backtracking, array-algorithms

I have a c++ program which calculates maximum of a array provided no two consecutive elements of array can be taken.
For eg: 
`7 3 4 6` will result in a answer of 13 .Here we chose 7 and 6 for optimal maximum.
Here is my recursive program for it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int n;

int findMax(int x,int ar[])
{
    if(x < n)
        return max( ar[x]+findMax(x+2,ar), findMax(x+1,ar));
    return 0;

}

int main(){
    int ar[]={1,7,4,4,9,5,12};
    n = sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0]);
    cout<<findMax(0,ar);
    return 0;
}
```

However **I am more interested in the indices of array which were chosen for this purpose by my program .How can I do that efficiently.** 
In the above program answer should be `1,4,6` as we chose 1st , 4th and 6th element of the array for the maximum.

**Note:** I am using 0 based indexing.

Thanks.

Comment: What I didn't get: How many elements may form the maximum? From your first example, I thought two (not consecutive) elements. In your second example, you want to choose three indices. Could you clarify this?

Comment: I believe I got it: A maximum is an element where predecessor and successor are lower (with special exceptions on first and last element). Can you confirm this?

Comment: Your code runs in O(Fibonacci(n)) time, which is going to be too slow for larger n. There's a linear-time dynamic program solution, which is also going to make it easier to return the indices.

Comment: @Scheff I think the example is a mistake -- the code is computing the subsequence with no consecutive elements that maximizes its sum.

Comment: @PaulHankin So, I don't need to excuse for my confusion... ;-)

Comment: Actually I was wrong and the example is correct -- the maximum is 7+9+12, which are at indices 1,4,6 in the array.

Comment: @Scheff we can choose any elements in the array provided none of the two are consecutive like element 0 and element 1 can't be taken..

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for my long line. I tuned your algorithm. It looks a bit strange but does what required.

Comment: @PaulHankin Could you please share that algorithm or where can I learn about it :)

Comment: I added an answer describing the algorithm, including how to reconstruct the indices. It's a fairly typical dynamic programming solution, so it's worth knowing the technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recurrence relation R(k) for the maximum sum of the first k elements of the array (with no adjacent terms) is:

```
R(0) = 0, R(1) = max(0, a[0])
R(k) = max(a[k] + R(k-2), R(k-1))
```

This is almost the same recurrence you're using in your code, but in your code your function returns the maximum sum of elements k and later.

Anyway, you can build a table of these values in linear time using dynamic programming. In pseudocode:

```
R = new array of length n+1
R[0] = 0
R[1] = max(0, a[0])
for i = 2 .. n
   R[i] = max(a[i-1] + R[i-2], R[i-1])
```

If you just want the maximum sum, you can return R[n]. But you can also reconstruct the indices easily. In pseudo-code:

```
indices(a, R):
    result = new empty vector
    i = n
    while i > 0
        if (i == 1 and a[0] > 0) or R[i] == a[i-1] + R[i-2]
            result.push_back(i-1)
            i -= 2
        else
            i -= 1
```

You'll have to reverse `result` to get the indices in increasing order.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the most effective solution but probably the one with least implementation effort:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int n;

pair<int, vector<int> > findMax(int x, int ar[])
{
  if (x < n) {
    pair<int, vector<int> > max1 = findMax(x + 2, ar);
    const pair<int, vector<int> > max2 = findMax(x + 1, ar);
    max1.first += ar[x];
    max1.second.insert(max1.second.begin(), x);
    return max1.first >= max2.first ? max1 : max2;
  }
  return make_pair(0, vector<int>());
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const vector<int> &vec)
{
  const char *sep = "";
  for (int value : vec) {
    out << sep << value; sep = ", ";
  }
  return out;
}

int main()
{
  int ar[]={1,7,4,4,9,5,12};
  n = sizeof ar / sizeof *ar;
  const pair<int, vector<int> > maxAr = findMax(0, ar);
  cout << maxAr.first << '\n'
    << maxAr.second << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
28
1, 4, 6
```

[**<kbd>Life demo on coliru</kbd>**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89cff00f24898aeb)

Thereby, the return value is extended with a `std::vector<int>` which holds the used indices beside of the current sum.

`std::max()` could be used if I would provide a suitable (overloadeded) `operator<()` for `std::pair<int, std::vector<int> >`. To not make things over-complicated, I just replaced `std::max()` by the resp. condition.

Comment: This a a good idea, but time complexity would be exponential.

Comment: @user_0 Actually, _time_ complexity didn't change compared to your original algorithm (if you don't consider the insertion into `std::vector`). Instead of `std::vector::insert()`, I could have used `std::vector::push_back()` which is a bit more performance friendly. (The resulting vector could be reversed finally.)

Comment: Yeah i could have used memoization in my code snippet but for simplicity i didnt :)

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will satisfy your need.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int n;
void findMax(int arr[], int in, pair< int, vector<int> > tempStore, 
pair< int, vector<int> > &resStore) {
    if(in >=n) {
       if(resStore.first < tempStore.first) {
            resStore.first = tempStore.first;
            resStore.second = tempStore.second;
       }
       return;
    }
    findMax(arr, in+1, tempStore, resStore);
    tempStore.first += arr[in];
    tempStore.second.push_back(in);
    findMax(arr, in+2, tempStore, resStore);
}
int main() {
    int ar[]={1,7,4,4,9,5,12};
    n = sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0]);
    pair< int, vector<int> > resStore, tempStore;
    findMax(ar, 0,tempStore,resStore);
    cout<<"Result Value: "<<resStore.first;
    cout<<"\nResult Index:\n";
    for(int i=0; i<resStore.second.size(); i++) {
        cout<<resStore.second[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```